# How to enable XD bit on Intel Core i3-350M?

Tags: windows-8, bios, nx

I own an HP G62 laptop (b85SS). I'm trying to install Windows 8 RP, but it says my CPU doesn't support it.

The CPU is an Intel Core i3-350M, which supports everything Windows 8 needs - SSE2, PAE, NX (in this case, XD).

From what I've read, it's HP's BIOS (Insyde) that disables XD by default and doesn't allow users to enable it. I updated the BIOS to the latest version and still can't enable it. I've also read I can enable it by changing bit 34 of the MSR (using an MSR editor), but I don't want to mess with this until I get some more information.

So my question is, is it possible to enable the XD bit using some kind of tool or software?

Comment: What's the exact error message you're getting? Really though, if you can't turn on XD via the utilities supplied by HP, you're probably out of luck.  If software could easily turn XD on and off, it'd be useless. :)

Comment: The error message is something like "CPU is not compatible with Windows 8".

Answer (score 2):

Laptop manufacturer BIOSes are notorious for providing rigid control structures - you basically get to control the boot order and a drive password, nothing more.  What many (myself included) do is to search for a cracked (custom) BIOS or request one on an overclocking forum where BIOS crackers hang out.  Usually a cracked BIOS will enable all options that can possibly be controlled by a BIOS, so if your function is not there there's no hope.

This will of course reset your boot order, but as another plus you'll be able to set more advanced configuration settings on the side as well (fan speeds, SATA hotplugging, etc.)